# Use X509Certificate2 to sign and validate ECDSA-SHA256 signatures

Tags: c#, ssl, sha256, x509certificate2, ecdsa

I used `OpenSSL` to create ECC certificates using `SHA256`. Now I want to use these certificates to sign data and to validate existing signatures.

I tried using the `DSACryptoServiceProvider`, but it only supports `SHA1` or `MD5`.

But it seems that `ECDsaCng` is able to support `ECDSA-with-SHA256`. The only problem that I have is that I don't know how to convert the Private and Public Key from my `X509Certificate2` into the necessary `CngKey`. I read another question where someone described how to convert the Public Key. But in order to be able to sign data, I need the Private Key, too.

**So is there a way to get the `CngKey` of the Private and Public Key out of the `X509Certificate2`?** The certificates are available in different formats. I have them as PFX file and separately as CER and PEM files.

I would prefer to stick with the `.NET Framework 4`, but if it's not possible at all to use it, I would also switch to `Bouncy Castle`.

Answer (score 7):

Support for this was added in .NET 4.6.1:

```
private static byte[] SignWithCert(X509Certificate2 cert, byte[] data)
{
    using (ECDsa ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey())
    {
        if (ecdsa == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cert must have an ECDSA private key", nameof(cert));

        return ecdsa.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    }
}

private static bool VerifyWithCert(X509Certificate2 cert, byte[] data, byte[] signature)
{
    using (ECDsa ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPublicKey())
    {
        if (ecdsa == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cert must be an ECDSA cert", nameof(cert));

        return ecdsa.VerifyData(data, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. v4.6.1 is unfortunately too high, I can only use v4.0.